# Bucket upload notification

Tags: bucket, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I use the Buckets function in Oracle Cloud and I would like to know if there is any way to send an email/sms notifying when a user uploads files to the bucket.

I studied the documentation and found only bucket creation warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried the `Emit Object Events` on OCI bucket.

You can check out this doc for ref : https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/oracle-cloud-infrastructure-events-with-apex-and-ords

You can check the object even types here : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Events/Reference/eventsproducers.htm#ObjectStor__object

Create object event : `com.oraclecloud.objectstorage.createobject`

When the user uploads the file object is getting created in the bucket so you can use this event in the notification.